# I used MVVM in fragment but when I click on back button it does not go to previous fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm

I have used MVVM architecture in fragment the networking call are working perfect and the UI are updated correctly. I load the fragment from previous fragment there is a back button when I click on back button it give error "No View found for ID #6722734". the Interesting thing when I remove the MVVM code then Its going back to previous fragment perfectly. Anyone expert can help I would really appreciate.

```
 private HealthGoalViewModel healthGoalViewModel;
    private FragmentHealthGoalBinding fragmentHealthGoalBinding;
    private boolean valid = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_health_goal, container, false);


        fragmentHealthGoalBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_health_goal);
        healthGoalViewModel = new HealthGoalViewModel(getActivity());
        fragmentHealthGoalBinding.setHealthViewModel(healthGoalViewModel);
        fragmentHealthGoalBinding.tvName.setText(GeneralUtilities.getSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString("user_name", ""));
        fragmentHealthGoalBinding.setPresenter(new Presenter() {
            @Override
            public void onClicked() {
                String userId = GeneralUtilities.getSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString("userID", "");
                String strWeight = healthGoalViewModel.targetWeight.get();
                String strDescription = healthGoalViewModel.description.get();

                healthGoalViewModel.sendRequest(strWeight, strDescription, userId);
            }
        });

        fragmentHealthGoalBinding.ivBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed(); // does not work
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

I'm calling the fragments from here

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

```
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.iv_back:
            GeneralUtilities.connectFragmentWithoutBack(getActivity(), new DashboardFragment());
            break;
        case R.id.ll_body_composition:
            GeneralUtilities.putIntValueInEditor(getActivity(), "highlighted_position", 1).commit();
            GeneralUtilities.connectFragmentWithBack(getActivity(), new BodyCompositionFragment());
            highlitedBackground();

            break;
        case R.id.ll_health_goal:
            GeneralUtilities.putIntValueInEditor(getActivity(), "highlighted_position", 2).commit();
            GeneralUtilities.connectFragmentWithBack(getActivity(), new HealthGoalFragment());
            highlitedBackground();
            break;
        case R.id.ll_social_info:
            GeneralUtilities.putIntValueInEditor(getActivity(), "highlighted_position", 3).commit();
            GeneralUtilities.connectFragmentWithBack(getActivity(), new SocialInfoFragment());
            highlitedBackground();
            break;
        case R.id.ll_health_info:
            GeneralUtilities.putIntValueInEditor(getActivity(), "highlighted_position", 4).commit();
            GeneralUtilities.connectFragmentWithBack(getActivity(), new HealthInformationFragment());
            highlitedBackground();

            break;


this is my GeneralUtilites Class

public class GeneralUtilities {
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public static Fragment connectFragmentWithoutBack(Context context, Fragment fragment){
        ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();
        return fragment;
    }


    public static Fragment connectFragmentWithBack(Context context, Fragment fragment){
        ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).addToBackStack("abc").commit();
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Abdullah; welcome to SO! Please post the code where you ADD the fragment via the Fragment Manager. Are you using `addToBackStack(null)` or similar?

Comment: Thank you for you swift response 

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).addToBackStack("abc").commit();

Comment: The interesting thing is when I removed the MVVM code then the backstack working charmly but with that code it does not work.

Comment: I think you're going to have to expand a little bit more, using MVVM or any other form of separation of concerns, should have no impact whatsoever in the FragmentManager and ActivitiyTaskManager behavior; there's something missing and we cannot see it because you only showed us 10 lines of code :)

Comment: let me show you the full code

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I have edited the code can you please check if you need anything else from my end then let me know and thanks for you help

Comment: Please understand that we (SO) have near-zero knowledge about your project; you need to take a step back; and debug your project; isolate the feature that is not working (which seems to be pretty basic) and take it from there; I see *various* code smells. why have the GenearlUtilities class with static methods? Why pass a context there if are in a fragment, you have access to the context, you have access to the FragmentManager, you don't need that.  you also *always* create a new fragment on clicks: `new HealthInformationFragment()` for e.g., etc. Good luck.